# Lists - additional alphanumeric item labels

Tags: feature-request, markdown, list

I think it would be a cool feature if list formatting allowed different alphanumeric labels (besides bullets):

```
1. First step has its own child steps 
    a. Lower
    B. Upper

    1.2 Step parent.child
    1.3 This is step1.child3

            Some formatted text

    I. Roman 
    II. would 
    III. be
    IV. cool

2. etc...
```

Thought about this when answering:
[Use gcc 4.2 in Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765157/use-gcc-4-2-in-xcode-4-2-and-ios-sdk-5-0/7939565#7939565)

Comment: I don't see the particular need for this. It deviates from the original Markdown syntax – and I hate it when the interpretation of syntax differs from site to site.

Comment: is SE markdown part of an open source project?  I cannot find it, must be looking in the wrong places

Answer (score 5):

I see a lot of users trying to post item lists using Alpha characters instead of Numerals.  like

> A.
>
> B.

or

> A)
>
> B)

like they were choices.  I think that it would be a good idea to include these in the formatting.  We already have the option of using either **numbers or bullets**  but I think that all sites could definitely benefit from also being able to use letters, it would open up **Roman Numerals** as well

Answer (score -1):

1. Lists in a list item:

   - Indented four spaces.

     - indented eight spaces.
   - Four spaces again.
2. Multiple paragraphs in a list items:
   It's best to indent the paragraphs four spaces
   You can get away with three, but it can get
   confusing when you nest other things.
   Stick to four.

   We indented the first line an extra space to align
   it with these paragraphs.  In real use, we might do
   that to the entire list so that all items line up.

   This paragraph is still part of the list item, but it looks messy to humans.  So it's a good idea to wrap your nested paragraphs manually, as we did with the first two.
3. Blockquotes in a list item:

   > Skip a line and
   >   indent the >'s four spaces.
4. Preformatted text in a list item:

   ```
   Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
   That's four spaces for the list
   and four to trigger the code block.
   ```

   ---

As you can see above, nested lists do exist. See [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists)

Comment: Sorry, I just clarified my Q, other alphanumeric labels, besides bulets.

Comment: 1. 2. 3. 1.?  Lists could use much improvement imho.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ woops, fixed that..